# Java text file input handling

Tags: java, inputstream, bufferedreader

I am trying to read data from a text file and I am not quite sure how to handle this.

For example, if my data looks like this in text file:

```
2   
3   
(0 1 1)   
(0 2 3)
```

And I want to save those values in following manner:

```
int a = 2;
int b = 3;   
int[][] c = new int[a][b];   
c[0][1] = 1   
c[0][2] = 3
```

Numbers in parenthesis are (row, column, value) for a 2-D array that I am supposed to fill out from the data.

I am extremely new to input stream. What do I have to do to make my program recognize parenthesis and data inside the parenthesis should be handled differently?

Comment: All you would need to do is use an if statement to figure out if the next character coming through the stream is a bracket.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to initialize an Util class like BufferedReader or Scanner, than you will be able to manage the txt file.

Here it is an example of a  piece of java code that takes all the numbers in the txt file as Double type, then it saves them into a list.

You can do the same with integers, or, simply format each line with the needed method (check BufferedReader and Scanner javadocs) as String to handle them as needed.

```
Scanner s = null;

s = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("YOUFILENAME.txt")));
        while (s.hasNext()) {
            if (s.hasNextDouble()) {
                \\\ YOURLIST.add (s.nextDouble ())
            } else {
                s.next();
            }   
        }
    } finally {
        s.close();
    }
```

To manage the chars like `(` you can use built-in methods of the String type, like `split ()` or `contains ()`

See also: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways you could this and this may not be the most elegant, but something like this works. I used a regex to split parenthesis.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
      Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

      // Read array dimensions
      String line = "";

      line = scan.hasNext() ? scan.nextLine() : null;
      if(line == null) {
        throw new Exception("Invalid input for 'a'");
      }

      int a = -1;
      try {
        a = Integer.valueOf(line);
      } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
        System.out.println("Input is not a number: " + line);
        return;
      }

      int b = -1;
      line = scan.hasNext() ? scan.nextLine() : null;
      if(line == null) {
         throw new Exception("Invalid input for 'b'");
      }
      try {
        b = Integer.valueOf(line);
      } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Input is not a number: " + line);
        return;
      }

      if(a <= 0 || b <= 0) {
         throw new Exception("Array sizes should be larger than 0");
      }
      int array[][] = new int[a][b];

      // Gather array values
      while(scan.hasNext()) {
          line = scan.nextLine();
          if(line.charAt(0) == 'q') { break; } // 'q' to exit
          setArray(array, line);
      }

      // Print array
      for(int i=0; i < array.length; ++i) {
          System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array[i]));
      }
    }

    // Returns true on set success, false otherwise
    private static boolean setArray(int[][] array, String input) throws NumberFormatException {
      Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\((\\d*?) (\\d*?) (\\d*?)\\)");
      Matcher match = regex.matcher(input);
      if(match.matches() && match.groupCount() == 3) {
        int a = Integer.valueOf(match.group(1));
        int b = Integer.valueOf(match.group(2));
        int val = Integer.valueOf(match.group(3));

        // Check bounds
        if(a >= 0 && a < array.length && b >= 0 && b < array[0].length) {
            array[a][b] = val;
        }
        else { 
            return false;
        }
      }
      else {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
}
```